# Cocoa Collapsible Panel UI Design

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, panel, collapsable

I'm trying to develop an interface on XCode 3.2.6 with Interface Builder. I'm planing to design an UI with collapsible panels like image below:

http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/TexturePacker_1.png

In this sample, there is 3 panels seen on the UI (Geometry, Layout and Output). When user collapses the Geometry panel, it shrinks and Layout panel moves up with Output panel. You can expand and collapse each panel individually.

are there any special technique to do that or do I need to use a custom control to achieve this view? If so, do you know which component set has this feature?